# Number of non-isomorphic groups of order 21

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, groups-enumeration

Let $G$ be  a group of order  $21$. Find the number of non-isomorphic groups of order $21$

**My solution:**
If  the group $G$ is commutative,then $G$ can be expressed as a direct product of cyclic groups of prime power order,i.e it is either $\mathbb  Z_3\times \mathbb Z_7$ or $\mathbb Z_{21}$ which is same

My problem is when $G$ is commutative.How to proceed here?

Comment: Do you know something about group of order pq?

Comment: This is a rather general hint: use [Sylow theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems).

Answer (score 2):

Let $p>q$ be primes. There exists a non-abelian group of order $pq$ *if and only if* $p\equiv 1 \bmod q$. Furthermore any tow non-abelian groups of order $pq$ are isomorphic. For a proof use the Sylow theorems. Also, one can find this result in many books. For $p=7$ and $q=3$ we obtain that there is exactly one non-abelian group of order $21$. The abelian groups are $C_{21}\simeq C_3\times C_7$.

Comment: why any two non-abelian groups are isomorphic?in which books I can find this

Comment: In a text on Sylow theorems, e.g., Theorem $4.5$ [here](http://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math101b/appS.pdf).